# React Native TextInput text flickers while going to next line

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Text inside text input is flickering while going to next line  ([video](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/akshay-fc6b9.appspot.com/o/.1yes.mp4?alt=media&token=2caaa9dc-4c87-44d0-b097-e63513aa0da6))

but problem solved if i give height prop instead of maxHeight to the textinput or specify number of lines ([video](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/akshay-fc6b9.appspot.com/o/.1no.mp4?alt=media&token=ff8d5c50-3956-4c68-af81-73173a1503aa))

[code](https://snack.expo.dev/@akshaykhapare/carefree-blue-croissant?platform=android)

im trying to achieve textinput like X (twitter) that detects mentions ,tags ,urls

Comment: Video links are not available. Please edit

Comment: video links are updated